# How to rename a package in all source folders with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

Eclipse allows renaming packages in the refactoring menu (`Refactor` / `Rename...`). However, the packages are only renamed in the current source folder.

Is it possible to perform the rename in all source folders of the project? This would be useful to keep the same package structure for the test classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think not.  [There is an Eclipse bug in status ASSIGNED about this.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=109988)

Despite 3 duplicates have RESOLVED_DUPLICATE status they are just waiting for the ASSIGNED 109988 to be resolved. I am not familiar with the eclipse community issue tracking process but it is misleading a bit. This is an old ticket anyway.